# LLVM 3.0 compiler error: cast of C pointer type to Objective-C pointer type 'id' requires a bridged cast

Tags: iphone, compiler-construction, casting, compiler-errors, llvm

I am trying to compile old iPhone application project using new LLVM 3.0 compiler.
I am getting this error:

**Automatic Reference Counting Issue: cast of C pointer type 'CGColorRef' (aka 'struct CGColor *') to Objective-C pointer type 'id' requires a bridged cast [4]**

for code:

```
UIColor *color1, *color2, *color3, *color4;

....

NSArray *colors =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)color1.CGColor, color2.CGColor, color3.CGColor, nil];
```

This code compiles without problems in older LLVM GCC 4.2 compiler.
What is the cause of that?
What are the most important things to learn when migrating to the LLVM 3.0 compiler?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because you're using the compiler's ARC mode (Automatic Reference Counting). For ARC to successfully statically track the reference count of objects that cross the toll-free bridges (Foundation to Cocoa and vice versa), you need to tell it that you've considered the situation. In general, either disable ARC or have a read of [The ARC documentation about casts](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#objects.operands.casts) to pick the appropriate solution.

However, here you have a bigger problem. `CGColorRef` (the type of `UIColorInstance.CGColor`) is *not* toll-free bridged to a Cocoa type, and so cannot be safely cast to a `id`. Why not just store the `UIColor`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was NOT compiler issue. It was ARC option set to YES by default in new Xcode 4.2 release. After setting it back to NO everything is fine now. Thx.

Comment: Be warned that things are probably *not* alright - you're casting what is effectively just a raw structure pointer to something the runtime will expect to be an `NSObject`. This is a recipe for pain!

Comment: Code comes from one of the Advanced iPhone Development podcast exampes so it seems it is acceptable it that particular case.

Comment: Don't believe everything you read on the internet.  I've found some fantastically bad example code in various podcasts, books, and sites.  It is a recipe for pain;  post it in a separate question if you want analysis as to why.