# iOS 5 - Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 error

Tags: ipad, ios5, ios-simulator

I dont know what happen here when I tried to compile with Xcode, the compiler show this statement, "Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 error". It says fatal error that:

***file '/Users/integraasp/Dropbox/code/FlipView/Classes/ColorHelper.h'*** has been modified since the precompiled header was built. It can build and run well on device but I can't test my code on simulator.

Before I got this error, I tried to copy the newest version of my code from dropbox. I don't know what to do since I've changed many line of code.... :'(

I've tried solution from these link, but unfortunately it's not work at all. Is there anyone can help me..? :(

[Convert to ARC - LLVM compiler 3.0 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972960/convert-to-arc-llvm-compiler-3-0-error)

[LLVM 3.0 compiler error: cast of C pointer type to Objective-C pointer type 'id' requires a bridged cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808360/llvm-3-0-compiler-error-cast-of-c-pointer-type-to-objective-c-pointer-type-id)

**

### Finally, I've found the error. :)

**

> Well, finally I've found the error. **prefix.pch** file for this
>   project declare was not correctly write all of header files of this project. I just
>   write down manually on **prefix.pch** all header files from my project
>   and it's done. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [XCode 4.1 fatal error: stdlib modified since the precompiled header was built](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071523/xcode-4-1-fatal-error-stdlib-modified-since-the-precompiled-header-was-built)

Comment: yeah, actually I don't understanding well this new Xcode, it have few changes from the older version... -,-a

Comment: Just a word of helpful advice. You can mark boris' answer as the correct answer by selecting the checkmark on the left side of his question. Once it's green then it's easy for us to find the answer that worked best for you! :)

Comment: thank you for the advice jackson... thanks boris for your answer... :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Cleaning build folder i.e. Option+Command+Shift+K, not just Product>Clean for the project usually solves this problem.

Answer (score 1):

try following step.

Set the project compiler to "LLVM GCC 4.2", instead of "Apple LLVM 3.0"; ARC is only supported when you use Apple LLVM. To set the project compiler, in your Project, under "Build Settings", and then under "Build Options", there is a settings for "Compiler for Objective-C". Change that value to "LLVM GCC 4.2

Comment: well, thank you for your response. But, It was answered before... :)

Comment: I think it is solve temporaly.... If it had an error, I will ask you again, guys.... :)